# How to map column names inside another (p)map function

Tags: r, purrr

I'd like to change each value in `mydf2` to its closest value in `attitude`'s corresponding column. For example we replace the first value in `mydf2`'s `complaints` column, 64.37888, with 64 since 64 is the nearest number in `attitude`'s `complaints` column. This should be easy enough, except I'd like the code to generalize to many column names. Whereas there are only three columns of interest in the example below, I'd like the code to also work if just add "raises" or "critical" to the end of the vector `cols_to_iterate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)
set.seed(123)
cols_to_iterate <- c("complaints", "learning", "advance")
mydf2 <- as.data.frame(map(attitude[cols_to_iterate], ~runif(6, 50, 100)))

map(cols_to_iterate, function(col_of_interest){
  pmap(mydf2, function(cols_to_iterate, ...){
    new_mydf2_col_val <- Closest(pull(attitude, col_of_interest), col_of_interest)
    return(new_mydf2_col_val)
  })
}
)

# Error in x - a : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I tried the above code, but the pmap anonymous function isn't recognizing `cols_to_iterate` as an input the same way as if I had manually entered function(c("complaints, "learning", advance")).

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @YifuYan, yeah that's a great point about `mutate_at()`, this is really more of a mock-up to do something more complex in `purrr`. Functionally what I'm hoping to do would yield an identical output as

```r
mydf2 %>% mutate_at(vars(complaints), list(~Closest(attitude$complaints, .)
           %>% mutate_at(vars(learning), list(~Closest(attitude$learning, .)
#etc etc
```

Comment: Misunderstood your question and didn't realize attitude is a data.frame. After reading your question more carefully, I just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `pmap` here as `pmap` is used for iterating through rows. You should use `map` instead.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)
set.seed(123)
cols_to_iterate <- c("complaints", "learning", "advance")
mydf2 <- as.data.frame(map(attitude[cols_to_iterate], ~runif(6, 50, 100)))

map2_df(mydf2,colnames(mydf2),function(column,colname){
    map_dbl(column,function(cell){
        Closest(attitude[[colname]],cell)[1] # use the first value in case there are two closest values
    })
})
```

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  complaints learning advance
       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1         64       75      72
2         90       75      72
3         70       75      55
4         90       72      72
5         90       75      63
6         53       72      52
```

Comment: ahhh this makes sense. I spent a lot of time mulling this over, I'm extremely grateful for your help!

Comment: By the way, if I also wanted to iterate row-wise on top of how the current code works (say, find the closest values in `attitude` again, but only among rows that are in the same arbitrary group as the given row in `mydf2`), would I just wrap the current `map2_df` inside a `pmap`?